# Android studio throwing: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Tags: java, android, windows, shell

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.3.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2.0)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\SG>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

C:\Users\SG>java --version
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

C:\Users\SG>java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

C:\Users\SG>set SDKMANAGER_OPTS=--add-modules java.se.ee

C:\Users\SG>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

C:\Users\SG>
```

I am new to this. Please help.
I am trying to use flutter on my system and I tried a few commands taking help from other StackOverflow questions and now I'm lost.